# My script is not recognizing my javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Brackets as my text editor. I have used this many times but this is the first time I have run into this problem. I get no errors when I write the code but when I run it, it doesnt work. I tried to debug it and opened the debugging tool in chrome. However, when i click on console it shows up empty. My code is listed below.

HTML Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="calc" id="calculator">
            <input type="text" name="#1" id="number1" enter code here" 
             placeholder="Enter Text" >
            <input type="button" name="tryme" id="tryme" value="Try Me" onclick="tryme();">
            <p id="answer" ></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
/*eslint-env browser*/

function tryme() {
    var str = document.getElementById("tryme");
    var res = str.slice(0,2);
    alert("aaa");
    if (res==("Py")) {
        document.write = str;
    }
    else{
     document.write = "Py" + str;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `document.write( str )` not `document.write = str`. That's overwriting the `document.write` function with `str`.